# Appending or Concatenating DataFrame via for loop to existing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Posted in the output you will see that this code take the Location column(or series), and places it in a data frame. After which, the first,second, and third part of the nested for loop then takes the first index of each column and then creates a dataframe to add to the first dataframe. What I have been trying to do is for loop through, going up one index each for loop, and then adding a new dataframe of repetitve data. However, when I try to print it, the dataframe will only print the first dataframe, and the last repetitive dataframe that it looped through. However I'm trying to make a huge dataframe that attaches a repetitive index data frame from 0-17. I have updated this to show the repetitiveness that I am looking for, but in a truncated way. I hope this helps. Thanks!

Here is the input

```
    for j in range(0,18,1):
        for i in range(0,18,1):
            df['Rep Loc'] = str(df['Location'][j:j+1])
            df['Rep Lat'] = float(df['Latitude'][j:j+1])
            df['Rep Long'] = float(df['Longitude'][j:j+1])
            break
print(df)
```

Here is the output

```
                                             Location   Latitude  
Longitude  \
    0   Letsholathebe II Rd, Maun, North-West District... -19.989491  
    23.397709   
    1                       North-West District, Botswana -19.389353  
    23.267951   
    2       Silobela, Kwekwe, Midlands Province, Zimbabwe -18.993930  
    29.147992   
    3   Mosi-Oa-Tunya, Livingstone, Southern Province,... -17.910147  
    25.861904   
    4   Parkway Drive, Victoria Falls, Matabeleland No... -17.909231  
    25.827019   
    5          A33, Kasane, North-West District, Botswana -17.795057  
    25.197270   
    6                       T1, Southern Province, Zambia -17.040664  
    26.608454   
    7   Sikoongo Road, Siavonga, Southern Province, Za... -16.536204  
    28.708753   
    8                 New Kasama, Lusaka Province, Zambia -15.471934  
    28.398588   
    9   Simon Mwansa Kapwepwe Avenue, Avondale, Lusaka... -15.386244  
    28.397111   
    10              Lusaka, Lusaka Province, 1010, Zambia -15.416697  
    28.281381   
    11  Chigwirizano Road, Rhodes Park, Lusaka, Lusaka... -15.401848  
    28.302248   
    12                T2, Kabwe, Central Province, Zambia -14.420744  
    28.462169   
    13   Kabushi Road, Ndola, Copperbelt Province, Zambia -12.997968  
    28.608536   
    14  Dr Aggrey Avenue, Mishenshi, Kitwe, Copperbelt... -12.797684  
    28.199061   
    15  President Avenue, Kalulushi, Copperbelt Provin... -12.833375  
    28.108370   
    16  Eglise Methodiste Unie, Avenue Mantola, Mawawa... -11.699407  
    27.500234   
    17  Avenue Babemba, Kolwezi, Lwalaba, Katanga, Lua... -10.698109  
    25.503816   

                                              Rep Loc    Rep Lat   
    Rep 
    Long  
    0   0    Letsholathebe II Rd, Maun, North-West Dis... -19.989491  
    23.397709  
    1   0    Letsholathebe II Rd, Maun, North-West Dis... -19.989491  
    23.397709  
    2   0    Letsholathebe II Rd, Maun, North-West Dis... -19.989491  
    23.397709  
                                                  Rep Loc    Rep Lat   

    Rep Long  
    0   1    North-West District, Botswana\nName: Loca... -19.389353  
    23.267951  
    1   1    North-West District, Botswana\nName: Loca... -19.389353  
    23.267951  
    2   1    North-West District, Botswana\nName: Loca... -19.389353  
    23.267951

                                                  Rep Loc   Rep Lat   
    Rep Long  
    0   2    Silobela, Kwekwe, Midlands Province, Zimb... -18.99393  
    29.147992  
    1   2    Silobela, Kwekwe, Midlands Province, Zimb... -18.99393  
    29.147992

                                                  Rep Loc    Rep Lat   
    Rep Long  
    0   3    Mosi-Oa-Tunya, Livingstone, Southern Prov... -17.910147  
    25.861904  
    1   3    Mosi-Oa-Tunya, Livingstone, Southern Prov... -17.910147  
    25.861904  
    2   3    Mosi-Oa-Tunya, Livingstone, Southern Prov... -17.910147  
    25.861904 

                                          Rep Loc    Rep Lat   Rep 
    Long  
    0   4    Parkway Drive, Victoria Falls, Matabelela... -17.909231  
    25.827019  
    1   4    Parkway Drive, Victoria Falls, Matabelela... -17.909231  
    25.827019  
    2   4    Parkway Drive, Victoria Falls, Matabelela... -17.909231  
    25.827019

                                          Rep Loc    Rep Lat  Rep 
    Long  
    0   5    A33, Kasane, North-West District, Botswan... -17.795057  
    25.19727  
    1   5    A33, Kasane, North-West District, Botswan... -17.795057  
    25.19727  
    2   5    A33, Kasane, North-West District, Botswan... -17.795057  
    25.19727
```

Comment: In my opinion the best is create some small data sample - 3-4rows and from this sample add desired output (`18` can be changed to e.g. `3`) in sample for better verifying output.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice when asking questions is to provide an example of what you want your output to look like. However, this is my best guess at what you want.

```
pd.concat({i: d.shift(i) for i in range(18)}, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can put an output up on here, as in like in someway edit the post?

Comment: @RicardoTheviscountMedley [**this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43579250/edit) is the same link labeled "edit" below your post.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was so tired that I missed it. Anyways, I have updated the details, if you want to take a look @piRSquared , also, if you can briefly explain you answer, that would be great as well.